# How to format csv output with php?

Tags: php, csv

it is my problem, that cannot formatting the csv output.
I can't close the elements with an apostrophe and separator with tab.
Thank you!
This is code & output example:

```php
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
fputcsv($fp, array("id", "title", "name"), "\t");
fclose($fp);
```

and I would like look this:

```
"id"   "title"   "name"
```

Comment: * I would like it to look like this the CSV output

Thank you!

Comment: do you want commas between them also?

Comment: Why not use a proper library for outputting CSV?

Comment: I do not want to separate commas with tabs only and string closing apostrophe